# Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'descritpion')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const homeController= require('../Controller/homeController');
const addTask= require('../models/schema')

router.get('/',homeController.home);
router.get('/task',homeController.task);

router.post('/addTask',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        
        
            let TodoTask = new addTask({
                description: req.body.description,
                category: req.body.category,
                date:req.body.date
            })
        
            let addTaskDetail=await TodoTask.save();
            res.status(201).render('/');
    } 
    catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
})


module.exports=router;
```

It shows me this error->
description: req.body.description,
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')

Please help to store the data in to the database

Comment: means that `req.body` is undefined - I see you have no body parsers

Comment: I added the body parser but still it see undefined

Comment: where did you add the body parser?

Comment: I change my code right now in my vscode but it still show me the same error

Comment: perhaps you *did it wrong™* - there is no way for us to tell

Comment: can you write the right code?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://pastebin.com/3Dm391bt) will help - sorry, but I don't use cjs, I'm a mjs person

Answer (score 0):

**Use middleware to accept json on server side.**

```js
//enable accepting json on server side.
app.use(express.json());
 
/*
* extra middlewares if needed in request body data extraction
*/

//parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it can only parse incoming Request Object if strings or arrays
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}));

//parse incoming Request Object if object, with nested objects, or generally any type.
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}))
```

Comment: still not running when I add this code

Comment: can you provide me your code that starts your server?

Comment: The code provided here by @AniketRaj will allow you to parse your `req.body` and therefore extract `description` but make sure it is placed before your route definitions (i.e above them in the file). If you have done that it means you are not sending any form data with a key named `description`. Have at look at your html `form` that posts to the `/addTask` route. You need to have an `<input name="description">`